# Difference between very low quality and unclear flag

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, unclear

I wish to know what is the difference between `very low quality` and `unclear` flag.

I flagged 2 questions, [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482180/build-liquidsmooth-lg-g2) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485761/edit-html-file-in-wordpress) as **very low-quality**.

Now, both my flags have been declined but both of the above questions are on hold now (they are on hold for being **unclear**).

So, what points should be taken into consideration while flagging :-
a) question as `very low quality`
b) question as `unclear`

Also, is there so much a subtle difference between the two that the `very low-quality` flag will be declined if the question is instead `unclear`

Comment: I got two flags declined because of flagging "barely salvageable" low quality posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of those are poor questions, but they at least form coherent sentences. They both need a lot more information from the OP before they can be answered, and one is likely off-topic. Putting them on hold as "unclear what you're asking" is the right choice until more information is given.

Only flag posts as "very low quality" when there's no chance of salvaging them. If a post looks like someone pounded their keyboard, or like it was run through every language in Google Translate before submission, go ahead and flag as VLQ. This flag is only for posts that we can delete immediately without waiting on more input from the OP, so please only use it when you can't make any sense at all out of a post.

Comment: it really seems to me that this VLQ flag is not widely used. People prefer voting to close as "unclear" or "too broad". I rarely see VLQ questions in review as well.

Comment: And why can this post be flagged as Very Low Quality? https://i.imgur.com/sASBY2H.png

Comment: @GillesHeinesch Please post a separate question instead of asking only one person in a comment.