# Declined flags should not be declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

As I found no other way to "fight" against all of my declined flags, I will do it here and explain why I think that none of the declines are correct.

### Post flag

[image: post flag]

Here you can see my declined post flag, which I issued on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285547/firebase-functions-notification-error-values-must-be-a-string). Sadly I cannot put up an extensive argument for this one because I do not have the ability to view deleted posts. So this post was deleted and that after it got at least four down votes.

Whatever was wrong with this post *will always match* "very low quality" by my guess. The posts that typically get a load of down votes in the first minutes are never very well written or understandable. Even if this flag was not 100% accurate and I might have been better off using a different flag, I still think that this is no reason for decline because this post was obviously not deleted for fun and got four down votes. That I flagged it at all should be valid enough and if I could see what the actual post was again I am pretty sure that I could make a good argument to why my flag was appropriate and maybe it is even obvious and the decline was completely off.

### Comment flag

[image: comment flag]

*Okay because this comment still exists, which I find absolutely ridiculous, I will have to include it here to explain my choice of flag.*

[image: comment]

To understand the context you will have to take a look at my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416780/how-to-send-to-miscellaneous-notification-channel).

This comment does not make any sense at all. So first of all, even if the comment was valid concerning my question, it *should have been **an answer***. Now we come to the better part because the comment is completely **off-topic**. I never asked for "How to create a notification channel in Android", which this comment is *answering*.

So this comment is first of all *an answer* and secondly it is *off-topic*.
In the above image you can see that there are only three broad options to flag a comment. None of the three accurately match what I just explained. The comment is neither "rude" nor "abusive" and also it did *not "require[] action by a moderator"* because if anyone had ever looked at the actual question it would have been totally obvious that the comment is inappropriate! Though the comment is in fact **not needed** and that is why I chose that option. For this one I hope that not only my decline will be removed, but also that comment.

Comment: I refrain myself to flag this post as too broad. I'm not really sure yet.

Comment: (oh, I didn't read the whole thread either. I don't really want to deep dive into all these flags. Just looking at your conclusion there are some things that are misunderstood around flagging, IMHO) "Flag reasons are sometimes wrongly picked".... but that has a chance of sending the flag to the wrong queue, causing work for the wrong people. It **should** be declined, there. And Moderator intervention is not "write your own reason"... it's for "hey mod, here is a case that should be removed/actioned, that no other flag, close or option I have cover. Can you take a look?"

Comment: *This leads me to the conclusion that I misunderstood the spam flag* Yes. On that first and second example nothing is advertized or promoted, nor do they sell us things. What do you think spam is?

Comment: There is no such things as 'but the flag in general applies'. Just because a post was deleted for different reasons doesn't mean your flag was correct. Different flags lead to different actions and consequences, it is important you learn how to use them correctly. Yes, you have misunderstood what the VLQ flag is for, as well as the spam flag. Neither post you flagged as spam fits the description of the flag, they do not *[Exist] only to promote a product or service*.

Comment: _"I thought that spam was the most appropriate flag because I did not see any reason why he went system specific and why he had to talk about Curl."_ - Did you consider downvoting instead?

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments! I refrain to believe that all of you just started at the bottom. I can remove the **Spam posts** part for you if you wish so. Please consider that all the other mentioned flags are not that controversial.

Comment: On some sites, low quality content, especially when posted at high volume, is sometimes referred to as spam. Stack Overflow is not one of those sites.

Comment: @Servy I have two posts. I would not consider that a wide range to be honest.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I'm not referring to any post other than this one.  This post has 10 votes, all in exactly the same direction, indicating that the community does not consider the actions you described controversial, but rather that there is pretty wide agreement of the community.

Comment: @Servy Hey, I understand that. I  am also able to read and from what I read everyone was just talking about the **Spam posts** part, which I now removed because it obviously was not accepted.

Comment: _"So this comment is first of all an answer and secondly it is off-topic."_ - 1. I have _never_ heard of a moderator deleting comments because they were answers, at least not in response to the "No longer needed" flag. If anything, a comment might be kept _because_ it has lots of information. 2. Moderators aren't necessarily domain experts. Your question was long and included the word "notification". Moderators don't usually spend a long time deciding what to do...

Comment: *this comment still exists, which I find absolutely ridiculous* It is not so ridiculous as at least two other users answered your question on the same track as the comment. They deleted their answer after you commented on those answers. Why didn't you do the same to the ridiculous comment? At least that could have helped to focus your question and raise awareness for those who want to answer that the reasonable looking comment might put users in the wrong direction.

Comment: @AndrewMyers And because they probably did "not [..] spend a long time deciding what to do" I asked this question to get a bit more time out of it.

Comment: @rene I guess that was a mistake. I know that you asked for my opinion and I hope that you really wanted to know it... I decided to not comment because I hate that what is happening to this question here right now, here it is okay because it is a Meta question, but on the technical side I find it to be really confusing to have too many useless comments that make you not read the useful ones. And that was **actually** my thought process to why I did not put another useless comment because that guy did obviously not read the comments I put below these answers and that was at the same time.

Comment: You're making things up. Both answers were days after the first comment was posted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA2JD.png

Comment: @rene I cannot see into this obviously, I just thought that I remembered correctly, obviously not.

Comment: Just a side note for something that doesn't work how you thought: Declined flags can't be reversed. You're stuck with that decline. Other than a short rolling ban, if you've flagged enough and they all get handled in the same short time frame, it really won't hurt you though.

Comment: A better way to go about making your argument would be to say "My flag x for y was declined, but I thought it should be approved because z. Am I misunderstanding how to use flag x?" for each of these situations separately. That is a question that will help you learn. However this question reads like you assume your flags are being incorrectly declined and are demanding that the declination be removed because you believe they are all correct, and you make a sweeping statement about a lot of flags at once. That setup is not productive to getting an answer.

Comment: @rene Oh, I'm not going to bother getting into the debate with the OP about how correct their flags were. :) I just figured I'd point out a fact that really, they can't argue with. (Unless there's a longer flag ban I don't know of and that's what you mean?)

Comment: @DavyM Yes that is a great way to approach it. I did not think that people read or react like this because this is one of my first times on Meta. I have read other cases of **declined flags** and there a moderator or another user answered and responded to every flag that was in question. I thought that this would or could happen with my issue as well. I think that, only because I want to express that I feel wrong about the declines, you can still discuss my points, like I would expect in any other human conversation.

Comment: But... You aren't exactly inviting positive feedback and discussion with an opening post that feels so ranty. You have to understand that on meta, about 95%, if not more, of users coming **aren't** ones to feedback and just fight tooth and nail with no other arguments than "but I am right!". It's an instinctive (sometimes admittedly, a wrong instinct) reaction to push back on these types of posts, simply because most meta veterans have seen this too often turn into a flame war. Now,with you case it may be wrong perception, but try to see it from that angle a bit

Comment: @Patrice No, I think that it is right perception. You are exactly right that I wrote this post way too aggressive for Meta and I did not realise that before posting it. I should have just read through it again and now I know it for the future. That is also the reason why I will not bother "correcting" it.

Comment: @creative I am.... Genuinely surprised by your response here. Thx for being open to hearing that and taking the feedback for future posts :). Meta is a weird beast sometimes... But we don't really bite ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both flags were correctly declined.

In the first case, "very low quality" flags aren't meant to be used on garden-variety bad posts, nor as some sort of super close vote. [They are meant for truly exceptional cases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269726/2751851):

> Only flag posts as "very low quality" when there's no chance of salvaging them. If a post looks like someone pounded their keyboard, or like it was run through every language in Google Translate before submission, go ahead and flag as VLQ. This flag is only for posts that we can delete immediately without waiting on more input from the OP, so please only use it when you can't make any sense at all out of a post.

In the second case, "no longer needed" is meant for comments that are too chatty, or that point out issues with a post that have already been dealt with (for instance, suggesting an edit that was already performed). The technical accuracy of a comment is not a factor when using it. It is also worth mentioning that [there is no ban on posting solutions as comments, even if it often a suboptimal thing to do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339396/2751851), and being a solution is not a valid reason to delete a comment.

Comment: I really appreciate this! The first one I can understand, sadly I cannot look into the question to see if it really was not "very low quality" and for the second one I thought that the point of creating a notification had "already been dealt with".

Comment: @creative Looking at the post of the first flag, I see a poor code dump question, but it isn't gibberish, nor about mining in Western Australia. As for the second one, there isn't much textual evidence of the matter being explicitly dealt with in the Q&A, and deleting a comment that does try to address the question due to irrelevance is a tall order. Perhaps if you had replied to the  comment pointing the issue, and the author then replied in turn with "I misread your question, sorry" without deleting their comment there would be a case for "no longer needed"; otherwise, it is a tough sell.

Comment: This actually make more sense the more I think about it. Before this I thought that just issuing a flag was the option with less effort involved, but I guess that this system is just not good enough and writing to the people is in fact the better option!

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot That is a good way of putting it. [Moderators are exception handlers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287878/2751851). Flags have narrow limits of applicability because most situations are meant to be handled through the usual content curation mechanisms -- upvotes, downvotes, close votes, edits, clarifying comments, etc. (Close flags, which you'll have access until you become able to cast actual close votes, are an exception, as they aren't sent to diamond moderators.)