# Why can this answer be flagged as "very low quality"?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, low-quality-posts, moderation

Some people may think, that this is a duplicate question because you could find answers on this question but I tried to find an answer and I didn't.

I read the following posts before I created this question:

- [Difference between very low quality and unclear flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269723/difference-between-very-low-quality-and-unclear-flag/269726?noredirect=1#comment678427_269726)
- [What qualifies as Very Low Quality, if not this?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260812/what-qualifies-as-very-low-quality-if-not-this)

I was just reviewing a few posts and as reviewers know, sometimes you get tests there to test how well you're paying attention. I got such a test then.

[image: Screenshot of the post]

I downvoted the answer. Yes this was correct, but then I read the entire answer from the test result and I noticed that you could also flag the post as "very low quality".

I read in various posts that the VLQ flag should only be used if moderator attention is needed as fast as possible.

> Only flag posts as "very low quality" when there's no chance of
>   salvaging them. If a post looks like someone pounded their keyboard,
>   or like it was run through every language in Google Translate before
>   submission, go ahead and flag as VLQ. This flag is only for posts that
>   we can delete immediately without waiting on more input from the OP,
>   so please only use it when you can't make any sense at all out of a
>   post.
>   *Source: 
>   [Difference between very low quality and unclear flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269723/difference-between-very-low-quality-and-unclear-flag/269726?noredirect=1#comment678427_269726)*

When should VLQ flags be used now? Is there no clear definition anywhere?

Comment: The answer looks link only (unless the question can be answered with only "you have to copy the same code in all activities"). Note, that the message you see is a generic one.

Comment: "voting to close is appropriate" -- obviously the message is *too* generic. How can you VTC an answer?

Comment: I'd flag that as NAA, but not VLQ.

Comment: @jhpratt I would've simply downvoted, *given the context we have*, *"you have to copy same code in all activity"* may well be an *attempt* to answer the question, sure it may be a bad one but it is an attempt regardless, and so not NAA.

Comment: Link to the audit review, for context?

Comment: I think you're right. But I also think it's an uphill battle; review audits are auto-generated so this happens quite a lot. Not to mention the accepted interpretation of any given flag seems to change with the phase of the moon

Comment: If you care about the value of SO as a resource then you will watch the video and rewrite the answer to contain the requisite info. Whether you should have to is irrelevant to the fact that closing it or making it harder to find converts a potential future problem into a definite immediate problem.

Comment: It is crap, it doesn't matter what you flag it as. There's no need to ponder about how to categorize crap, just delete it.

Comment: My flags got all deleted after I flagged such posts for VLQ @Lundin

Comment: @GillesHeinesch Yeah we have a bit of a crap-hugger problem at meta. Meta residents who never even use the main site thinks it is more important to categorize crap than to keep the main site clean...

Comment: @Lundin I am glad to inform you that we have made absolutely no progress on this [in past 10 months or so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368428/5894241).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a question on meta.stackexchange.com [What exactly does a VLQ flag do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181796/what-exactly-does-a-vlq-flag-do) with a fairly recent [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291263/377987) explaining how VLQ flag works.
Basically, the VLQ flag is used to bring attention of people who can decide if the post is worth keeping on the site or not, as it says in the quote you provided:

> This flag is only for posts that we can delete immediately without waiting on more input from the OP

Note that not only moderators can delete posts, people with 20k rep or more can vote to delete answers, and 10k+ users can vote to delete questions. With enough votes, post can be deleted by users.

The VLQ flag is considered acceptable for audits, probably because it's not unreasonable to think that this post does not add anything of value to the site and could be deleted.